Transition to below cell after deleting cell in vscode notebook
Suppose I have cells A, B, and C (in that order) in a vscode .ipynb notebook. If I'm on cell B and delete (escape + x), I would like cell C to be the new active cell instead of cell A. Sometimes this happens and sometimes it doesn't. Is there a way to make it automatic?
